# Logic of conflict resolution

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, cherry-pick

I have simple test repository - just 1 file and several commits (creation of the repository is described at the end). I'm trying two variants of cherry-pick operations and I don't understand logic of conflict resolution:

If I do: 
`git cherry-pick test1`

Git detects a conflict in string 1: 'change-1' <-> 'test-1'.
It's clear.

If I do: 
`git cherry-pick test2`

Git doesn't detect a conflict and makes a new commit! It seems string 'test-1' is lost in this case.

I wonder why doesn't Git detect a conflict in the second case?

---

Creation of the repository

1.At the beginning I have an empty repositiory and one text file test.txt with the following content:

```
delimiter
footer
```

2.

```
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt -m 'v1'
```

3.
    test.txt is changed:

```
change-1
delimiter
footer
```

4.

```
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt -m 'v2'
git branch main HEAD
```

5.

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

6.
    test.txt is changed:

```
test-1
delimiter
footer
```

7.

```
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt -m 'v1_1'
git tag test1 HEAD
```

8.
    test.txt is changed:

```
test-1
delimiter
test-2
footer
```

9.

```
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt -m 'v1_2'
git tag test2 HEAD
```

10.

```
git.exe checkout main
```

The reporitory will look like:

```
v1_2 (tag 'test2')
 |
 |
v1_1 (tag 'test1')
 |
 |     v2 (branch 'main')
 |       |
v1--------
```

Then I do the first OR the second variant of cherry-pick.

Comment: How many branches do you have?

Comment: I have two chains of commits. One of them is a branch ('main'). Commits in the second chain marked by tags ('test1' and 'test2') – see the repository enclosed.

Comment: as a general rule: do not post links. Post the graph of you branches

Comment: if you look at the tag docs they are ways of marking a commit. cherry pick docs only refer to branches, heads. "Two chains of commits" sounds like two branches.

Comment: changed the post

Comment: Don't make changes so close to each other.  Git doesn't look at individual lines, it looks at regions ("hunks") as changes.  Try your example again making changes in different regions of a multi-line file.

Comment: Sorry but I get conflicts on both cherry-picks. Granted I did this in a rush, but it seems it should fail both times. Maybe somebody else can help you

Comment: @EdwardThomson I understand that if to try some other examples a conflict will be detected but I offered just this example and there are no conflicts. Honestly speaking I'm not sure it's safe to rely on Git functionality in operations of merge changes (cherry-pick, merge, rebase). It may be I don't understand something.

Comment: @efekctive I get a conflict in the second case if I do merge instead of cherry-pick (git merge test2) but with cherry-pick – no conflict.

Comment: I followed your step and I can't reproduce. Busy now :-}